# Eclipse and MinGW seem to be executing out of sequence

Tags: c

Working on a simple C program using basic I/O. printf and scanf to get started.
Using Visual Studio 2019 and Eclipse with MinGW.
The program has several printf statements followed by scanf_s to get an input. I was expecting that printf statements would be executed first and then scanf_s would read the keyboard input.
How in Eclipse that's not what happens. Seems that scanf_s is executed first and then printf statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s;
    printf("** Service Ticket Center **\n");
    printf(" Choose from the following options.\n");
    printf(" 1. Create new ticket.\n");
    printf(" 2. Update ticket status.\n");
    printf(" 3. Delete ticket.\n");
    printf(" 4. Find ticket.");
    scanf_s("%d", &s);
    return 0;
```

Ran same code in Visual Studio and printf statements were executed first followed by scanf_s as expected. It seems like Eclipse is the issue.

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` right before the `scanf_s`. Perhaps Eclipse is doing something weird that affects buffering.

Comment: I/O windows inside IDEs often work differently from genuine terminals / terminal  windows / *etc*..  There are technical reasons for that.  You really ought to test programs that perform I/O with their standard streams in a genuine terminal window, as that's more reflective of how they would actually be used outside of development.  I anticipate that if you had done that with your original code then you would have seen behavior different from that seen in *either* IDE.

Comment: It seems that in order for printf() output to be displayed in the Eclipse CDT console, fflush(stdout) is required. Found a thread discussing this issue in the Eclipse Community forum https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156519/ and this issues has been around for some time now. Command line works fine. Visual Studio and CodeBlocks consoles don't have this issue.